# flask deployment using internal werkzeug development server

Tags: python, deployment, flask, werkzeug

Why is it [not recommended to use the flask/werkzeug internal development webserver in production](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/serving/)?  What sort of issues can arise?

I'm asking because in work I'm being forced to do so and use a make shift cron to re-run the service every day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're having to use a cron job to kill & restart it on a daily basis, you've already found a *major* issue with using the Flask development server.  The development server is not written for stability, longevity, configurability, security, speed or much of anything other than convenience during development.

A proper WSGI setup will be faster, handle multiple connections properly and, most importantly for you, periodically restart your app process to clean out any cruft that might build up.

Comment: You're right.  lets say speed, efficiency or tidiness meant nothing!  Are there any definite gothca's that will really seal the argument for me.

Comment: @nialloc All the cool kids will be laughing at you?

The biggest one I can think of is that security issues in a 'real' server would get fixed quickly while those in a dev server would be of a lower priority.  I guess if this is just an internal thing with trusted users that won't even really carry much weight.

Comment: Because only one process is running its abysmally slow under load.  If lost of memory is being use the process exits with a -11 status!  Apache was invented so we didn't need to suffer this way :-)  Its so bad it is not funny

Comment: I've ran into issues where the dev server just hangs. No requests will go through. I think it is because an HTTP client didn't close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a network call inside the response handler that had no timeout. Something went wrong and it was waiting for a while (I was using the `requests` module), and then apparently never recovered.

Since Werkzeug server had only one thread, the whole development server became completely unavailable.