# running Flask jQuery example under Apache proxy

Tags: jquery, python, apache, flask, mod-proxy

I can successfully run the [Flask jQuery example](http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample) (as referred near bottom of [Flask's "AJAX with jQuery"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery) page.) It runs on the flask development server, and is accessible at `http://localhost:5000`.

How do I proxy the page so that I can access the same app under `http://localhost/jqueryexample`?

I added this to my Apache VirtualHost entry thinking it will do the trick:

```
ProxyPass /jqueryexample http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse /jqueryexample http://localhost:5000/
```

But the new URL gives the 404 error:

```
GET http://localhost/_add_numbers?a=6&b=2 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I get the example to run correctly under "canonical URL" (not sure if that's the right terminology)? Or, how to change the app or Apache configuration in order to get this jQuery example running for both URLs?

---

BTW, here's how you download and run the vanilla [Flask jQuery example](http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample) in question:

```
git clone http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask 
cd flask/examples/jqueryexample/ 
python jqueryexample.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after looking into this further, I think I answered my own question:

Apparently, instead of running the flask development server and trying to proxy it through Apache httpd, it's best to deploy the app directly to Apache using mod_wsgi. Guidelines on how to do this are well documented [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi). In fact, for production, the dev server is not at all recommended (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592161).)

As for deploying the [jQuery Flask example](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample) itself, here's what you do (assuming your DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html`):

```
# Get the example code.
git clone http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask 
cd flask/examples/jqueryexample/

# Create WSGI file.
echo "\
import sys\
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/jqueryexample')\
from jqueryexample import app as application\
" > jqueryexample.wsgi

# Deploy to httpd.
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/jqueryexample
sudo cp -r * /var/www/html/jqueryexample/
```

Now add this to your VirtualHost:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /jqueryexample /var/www/html/jqueryexample/jqueryexample.wsgi
<Location /var/www/html/jqueryexample>
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
</Location>
```

Then restart httpd. Now check out the running app at `http://localhost/jqueryexample`. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Apache install in front of me but if you are proxying the app shouldn't you change line 6 of the index.html from

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
```

to

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/jqueryexample/_add_numbers', {
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work - there's no error, but it does not run the  `_add_numbers` service. In addition, now `http://localhost:5000` gives the 404 error.